# How can I get BeautifulSoup info in the same row?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently web scraping and would like to get the specifications on the same row. When I currently print it column 2 looks like this:

```
text
text
text
text
text
```

I would like to get it all on the same row like this

```
text text text text text
```

so i can later chop it up into different columns in Excel later.

Is there maybe a transposing command I could use or something else?

Code:

import requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


with open('Oslo.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    fieldnames = ['column1', 'column2']
    skriver = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    skriver.writeheader()


    def data(page_number):
        URL = 'https://www.url.com/' + str(
            page_number) + '&sort=PUBLISHED_DESC'

        page = requests.get(URL)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        ads = soup.findAll('h2', class_="ads__unit__content__title ads__unit__content__title--fav-placeholder")

        for data in ads:
            id = data.find('a')
            link = (id['id'])
            url = 'https://www.url.com/'+str(link)
            page = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            ads = soup.findAll('div', class_="u-word-break")
            for stats in ads:
                address = stats.find('p', class_="u-caption")
                specs = stats.find('dl', class_="definition-list definition-list--cols1to2")

                skriver.writerow({'column1': address.text.strip(), 'column2': specs.text})
    for x in range(1, 2):
        data(x)
print('Ferdig, du kan åpne oslo.csv')
```

EDIT: Scraping from the website is illegal, so I removed the URL.

Comment: Either share the URL or edit your question with a sample of the `HTML` you're working, otherwise this is not reproducible.

Comment: @baduker I have now posted the full script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `specs.text` is a string that contains `\n` new lines. You can split it, then join it back with just a space. Ie `' '.join(specs.text.split())`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


with open('Oslo.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    fieldnames = ['column1', 'column2']
    skriver = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    skriver.writeheader()


    def data(page_number):
        URL = 'https://www.url.com/' + str(page_number) + '&sort=PUBLISHED_DESC'

        page = requests.get(URL)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        ads = soup.findAll('h2', class_="ads__unit__content__title ads__unit__content__title--fav-placeholder")

        for data in ads:
            id = data.find('a')
            link = (id['id'])
            url = 'https://www.url.com/'+str(link)
            page = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            ads = soup.findAll('div', class_="u-word-break")
            for stats in ads:
                address = stats.find('p', class_="u-caption")
                specs = stats.find('dl', class_="definition-list definition-list--cols1to2")

                address = ' '.join(address.text.split()) 
                specs = ' '.joins(specs.text.split())   #<-- changed here
                
                skriver.writerow({'column1': address, 'column2': specs})

    for x in range(1, 2):
        data(x)
        
print('Ferdig, du kan åpne oslo.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It does however not seem to get the text on the same row. Thank you for your time though. I also removed prispanel line

Comment: share the url. Or show me what you mean. This should work.

Comment: The only other thing I can assume/think is that you are confusing same line as not being on the same row. If the text have `\n`, it means it's being printed on a new line (however it is on the same row). I made a slight adjustment in the code. So try that and see what that looks like.

Comment: I have posted the full script now. I guess I would like to get it on the same line then. Sorry for my miswording

Comment: ya. thats what was happening. The `specs` text is with newlines. Simply split on the whitespace, then join them. Try the code I modified above.

Comment: That is exactly what I was hoping for! Thank you so much!